# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4, datatables

Jquery datatable is not loading for some user ids. it shows this error in chrome

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null

and in firebug

> TypeError: a is null return a.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" ).toLowerCase();

is this the jquery plugin issue or my php code (laravel) code.. i've been debugging this for one day.. didn't find the cause. please if anyone knows tell me what triggers this error?

Comment: have you added jquery ?

Comment: @nirmal yes.. jquery 1.10.2.js is loaded...

Comment: can you give some example with jsfiddle and static html

Answer (score 1):

This is because `a` is not what you expect, it is `null`.
Update code:

```
if (a) return a.replace( /<.*?>/g, "" ).toLowerCase();
```

If the code is in third-party library then, you are missing something.

Comment: @Ammu Then you need to update your code on how you are using that plugin. See their docs